# Llama a servicio web desde java

Tags: java, webservice, soap, axis

tengo este código:

```
    ServiceClient cliente = new ServiceClient();
    cliente.setTargetEPR(new EndpointReference("http://11:133:43:5776/css/ejemplo.cls"));
    Options options = new Options();
    options.setTransportInProtocol("http");
    cliente.setOptions(options);            
    String xml = "";

    try {
        OMFactory fac = OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory();
        // http://CS.Servicios/ServicioWeb, obtenerDato, 30
        OMNamespace omNs = fac.createOMNamespace("http://CS.Servicios/ServicioWeb","servicioPort");
        OMElement entidad= fac.createOMElement("parametroEntrada", omNs);
        OMElement value = fac.createOMElement("30", omNs);
        value.addChild(fac.createOMText(value, xml));
        entidad.addChild(value);
        cliente.fireAndForget(value);
         OMElement response = cliente.sendReceive(entidad);

        response.serialize(System.out);
    } catch (XMLStreamException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Y llevo varias semanas intentando conectarme a un servicio web lo cual no he conseguido todavía, no sé qué estoy haciendo mal dado que he consultado varias fuentes y se supone que así es como se establece una conexión. Eclipse me devuelve la siguiente excepción:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Mensaje SOAP mal creado.
at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:555)
at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:531)
at com.desic.sanidad.model.dao.inspeccionelectronica.InspeccionElectronicaDAO.callWebService(InspeccionElectronicaDAO.java:295)
at com.desic.sanidad.model.dao.inspeccionelectronica.InspeccionElectronicaDAO.obtenerContenido(InspeccionElectronicaDAO.java:240)
at com.desic.sanidad.services.InspeccionElectronica.consultarDocumento(InspeccionElectronica.java:191)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:121)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Me preguntaba si alguien sabe cómo conectarse a un servicio web o tiene alguna sugerencia para mi código.

Muchas gracias.